# how to set color transparent dynamically in android ? Like 10% 20% to 100%

Tags: java, android, colors

I know how to set a static color like **#1Abf6116**

```
    100% — FF
    95% — F2
    90% — E6
    85% — D9
    80% — CC
    75% — BF
    70% — B3
    65% — A6
    60% — 99
    55% — 8C
    50% — 80
    45% — 73
    40% — 66
    35% — 59
    30% — 4D
    25% — 40
    20% — 33
    15% — 26
    10% — 1A
    5% — 0D
    0% — 00
```

color code is  = "**#bf6116**"
 I want to set color like 
if user set **10** than color is **#1Abf6116**
i want to get value like **1a** if user set **10%** if user set 20% than i need **33**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//simple way to transparency set dynamicly any View 
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
String has = "#";
String PR_transparency = "50";// this text background color 50% transparent;
String og_color = "FF001A";

tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(has+PR_transparency+og_color));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Map then :

```
//Initial color
String color = "#bf6116";

//Create a map which hold percent and its corresponding String
Map<Integer, String> mapPercent = Map.of(100, "FF", 95, "F2", 10, "1A");

//user input, to explain I use a static variable
int userInput = 10;
if(mapPercent.containsKey(userInput)) {
    //Use replaceFirst or subscring to put the corresponding String
    color = color.replaceFirst(
        "#(.*)", //the regex match # as group 1 and the rest as group 2
        //put the corresponding string between the two groups
        String.format("$0%s$1", mapPercent.get(userInput)) 
    );
}


System.out.println(color);//result in this case is #1Abf6116
```

Note : `Map.of` from Java 10, you can use an ordinary map and put the inputs